# Transfer data from view to url

Tags: python, regex, django, url, view

I'm working on my django app, and I have problem with pass year to url. I use CVB as view. Below is my solution, but isn't working.

Here is my view:

```
class EventsListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'events/production_list.html'
    model = Events

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EventsListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        year_season = Events.objects.filter(is_active=True).last()
        context['year'] = year_season
        return context
```

Here is my url:

```
url(r'^/events/(?P<year>)$', EventsListView.as_view()),
```

Comment: Your group pattern is empty. Did you mean to write anything like `r'^/events/(?P<year>.+)'` (to match all the rest after `/events/`)? BTW, if you plan to just match 4 digits at the end of the string, then your regex should look like `r'^/events/(?P<year>\d{4})$'`

Comment: Also suggest you to using decimal `url(r'^/events/(?P<year>[-\d]+)/$', EventsListView.as_view()),`

Answer (score 0):

You can change your url to like this:

```
url(r'^/events/(?P<year>\d{4})$', EventsListView.as_view()),
```

this assuming you're using year like 2017.

this would parse urls from `/events/2017/` to `2017` as `year`.